# CSS is not loading in Firefox?

Tags: html, css, browser, encoding, web

I made a simple responsive website and everything is working great when browser reads file from my computer but when I put it on my server Mozilla is not loading CSS. It loads fine in Chrome and IE.

**Here is the HTML code**:

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Mate Ajdukovic | Developer</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css\normalize.css">
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Changa+One|Open+Sans:400italic,700italic,400,700,800' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css\main.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css\responsive.css">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
</head>
```

**And CSS (in main.css) starts with this**:

```
body {
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
 }

#wrapper {
    max-width: 940px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0 5%;
 }
```

Is it a problem with encoding? Is there anything I should put in main.css and responsive.css file?

I didn't change any settings in Mozilla and my version is 31.0.

Website: [http://test.mateajdukovic.com](http://test.mateajdukovic.com/)

Thanks!

Comment: the style uses webkit. This only load in chrome. Thats why the css is not loading in mozilla.

Comment: Don't confuse Mozilla and Firefox. It's like calling Internet Explorer "Microsoft" except that Netscape didn't supply a browser called "Microsoft" in the 90s.

Comment: @Quentin haha my bad, what a mistake, thanks for noticing me, I edited title. ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The errors are:

```
"NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://test.mateajdukovic.com/css%5Cnormalize.css"
"NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://test.mateajdukovic.com/css%5Cmain.css"
"NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://test.mateajdukovic.com/css%5Cresponsive.css"
```

Try changing the `\` to `/` in your HTML.

Comment: Give this man a cookie, I don't have enough reputation to vote it up but it fixes my problem. Really newbie mistake. Thank you! :)

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure But according to me you should use forward slash.

```
instead of "\" use "/" in your path of hreg tag
```

i.e.

use this:

```
<meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Mate Ajdukovic | Developer</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/normalize.css">
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Changa+One|Open+Sans:400italic,700italic,400,700,800' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/responsive.css">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

Rest all seems good.

Comment: Thanks man, that was a problem. I would vote it up but don't have enough reputation. :)

Comment: @edvard, no issues.. your comment is enuff. ;)